# A combinatorial inequality involving Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: inequality

> Prove:
>   $$
> \sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2} \right]}{n \choose k}^2 f_k 
> >
> \frac{4^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]}}{ \left(\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] +1\right)^2} \left( f_{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]+2}-1 \right),
> \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}
> $$
>   where $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number ($f_0 = 1, f_1 = 1, f_{n+2} = f_{n}+f_{n+1}$) and $\left[* \right]$ is the greatest integer part of $*$

To solve this problem I tried to write the left side as product of two sums and use properties of fibonacci and binomial using classic inequalities and simplify each term. I did not get the result.Proposed by Mr. Jalil Hajimir to RMM

Answer (score 2):

I'm tired/lazy, so this is isn't fully thought through. I'm off by a factor of 2. If it's not an arithmetic mistake, then the rearrangement inequality is very loose and could be tightened up more or see the note at the end.

---

**Hint:** $\sum_{i=1}^k F_i = F_{k+2} - 1$

For odd $n = 2m+1$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^m { 2m+1 \choose k}^2 = \frac{1}{2} {2(2m+1) \choose 2m+1 } >  \frac{1}{2} \frac{ 4^{2m+1}}{4m+3} > \frac{1}{2} \frac{4^m} {m+1 } $$

Since $F_k$ and $ { n\choose k}^2$ are in increasing order, apply rearrangement inequality to get

$$  (m+1) \sum { n \choose k}^2 F_k \geq \sum { n \choose k }^2 \times \sum F_k  > \frac{1}{2} \frac{ 4^m } { m+1} \left( F_{m+2} -1 \right)$$

For even $n$, do something similar, keeping track of the terms and floor functions.

---

Note: $ { 2n \choose n } \geq \frac{4^n} { \sqrt{4n} }$, which would easily give the desired result (for large enough $m$). However, I can only [quote it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), not prove it.

Comment: seems the adition of the terms is giving yiou that, Can you give a numerical example for which it is not true

Comment: $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{n}{2} \right]}{n \choose k}^2 f_k 
>
\frac{4^{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]}}{ \left(\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right] +1\right)^2} \left( f_{\left[ \frac{n}{2} \right]+2}-1 \right),
\qquad n \in \mathbb{N}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm deleting these comments. The bound is very loose, so you should be able to work form this.

Comment: the upper bound in addition is not n. It is n/2

Comment: @Keon Yes, which is why I have a factor of 1/2. I made that explicit in "for odd n = 2m+ 1, sum from k = 0 to m".